# How To Call this Animation in onCreate() in Android?

Tags: android, animation, oncreate

I am following this [link](https://medium.com/@ayushpguptaapg/how-to-add-shine-glare-effect-on-an-imageview-ab3e9e660307) for my animation Requirement. 
**https://medium.com/@ayushpguptaapg/how-to-add-shine-glare-effect-on-an-imageview-ab3e9e660307**

This has done on button click listener. Which is working fine. But i want to do it without button click as this animation starts as the activity load. 
I have searched alot, but didn't find any simple solution.
Can anybody tell me the simple solution.
Thanks in advance.

---

@ismail, i am using your this code, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button shinebtn;
    ImageView img,shine;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          img = findViewById(R.id.img);
        shine = findViewById(R.id.shine);
         shinebtn=findViewById(R.id.button);


        doAnimation();


}
    public void doAnimation(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, img.getWidth()+shine.getWidth(),0, 0);
                animation.setDuration(1000);
                animation.setFillAfter(false);
                animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                shine.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        shine.startAnimation(animation);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

just write the code after setting your elements  in `onCreate()`

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(yor_layout_source);
    ....

    ....
}

 @Override
 public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();  
  //do your animation code here 

 }
```

and here your animation function :

```
 public void doAnimation(){
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, img.getWidth()+shine.getWidth(),0, 0);
            animation.setDuration(550);
            animation.setFillAfter(false);
            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
      shine.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               shine.startAnimation(animation);
        }
      });
    }
  }).start();


    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I have already tried this thing, also applied your's code. but when i use this code in button then it works. Without button it doesn't work. Is there any other solution for it?

Comment: i want to send you my code, but Stack overflow is not allowing me, how can you will review my code?

Comment: so you told me that when you put my code is button it works , but like this doesn't work , right ?

Comment: No brother, i didn't try your code in button. I am talking about the other code. When i put it in button, then it works just like they showed. But i want to call the animation when activity launch on image view.

Comment: Please check my edit and try to put the animation code in on resume as mentioned